# Expectation Maximization on Multivariate Gaussian Mixture Model for clustering

Tags: clustering, maximum-likelihood, multivariate-normal-distribution, expectation-maximization, model-based-clustering

I have a dataset with 1000 observations and two features that define those N=1000 data points. Hence it is 1000*2 input matrix. I need to cluster them into k clusters.

I am not understanding the E-M algorithm clearly.

1. How to take prior weights (whose sum should be 1, for all gaussian distributions for every data point) ?
2. Next, to derive the pdf, should i calculate mean across every feature vector ? So, mean will be 2 values for 2 features. Then, how can I subtract mean(feature=1,2) from X(i=1:N) in the pdf function..because that would again make me to consciously choose x.

Maybe its something very basic I am not able to crack in the whole chicken-egg problem.

PS: I am coding everything from scratch to get full understanding and code control.
So far, I have written the functions for

1. multivariate Gaussian PDF,
2. Max Log Likelihood estimation,
3. K means algorithm with centroid reallocation & points association till convergence,
4. Euclidean & Mahalanobis distance calculation
5. Covariance matrix calculation

Any help is much appreciated !

Comment: The EM-algorithm requires, as you correctly note, an initialisation (like prior weights, prior means etc.). How to choose this is *not* part of the algorithm itself. There are various more or less sophisticated ways to do this (unfortunately I'm not aware of a review paper even though it may exist; it's scattered all over the literature), and the outcome of the algorithm may depend on this. You may also try out several random initialisations and then choose the best result in terms of final likelihood that you get.

Comment: Here is how the popular mclust package does it (Section on "Initialization of the EM-algorithm"):  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5096736/